# Different formatting on context menu items based on data template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a working dynamic context-menu but there seems to be an issue with the XAML-formatting. To me, it seems as the first template selected will be used for all the menu items.

[image]

I would like to achieve a result where the icons are placed in the normal standard location on the left highlighted column and I could still customize the right-side XAML-content for each menu item separately as defined in their `DataTemplate`.

Heres the XAML-code snipped, used with `ListBox`

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ModelContextMenu}"
                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContextMenuItemDataTemplateSelector}">
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

And the data templates for different menu items:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ChangeColorMenuItem" DataType="MenuItem">
    <DockPanel>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayName}"
                Command="{Binding Command}">
      </MenuItem>
      <xctk:ColorPicker
        SelectedColor="{Binding DataContext.SelectedColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:View}}}"
        Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    </DockPanel>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalMenuItem" DataType="MenuItem">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayName}"
              Command="{Binding Command}">
      <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
      </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
  </DataTemplate>
```

and finally the template selector class:

```
public class ContextMenuItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (container is FrameworkElement element && item is ContextMenuCommand commandItem)
        {
            switch (commandItem.MenuType)
            {
                case ContextMenuType.Normal:
                    return
                        element.FindResource("NormalMenuItem") as DataTemplate;
                case ContextMenuType.ChangeColor:
                    return
                        element.FindResource("ChangeColorMenuItem") as DataTemplate;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Each `MenuItem` content is capsulated in the list which is bind to the `ContextMenu`. The objects in the collection do contain all the data for each `MenuItem`, such as icon, display name, and `ICommand`.

```
public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuCommand> ModelContextMenu => _selectedModel.Commands;
```

---

**EDIT 2**

The desired (standard) icon location marked with blue crosses on the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be two inner `MenuItem` because of the data templates in question.
The problem was solved by defining `ItemTemplate` and a custom `ItemContainerStyle` in the following way:

**DataTemplates**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ChangeColorMenuItem" DataType="MenuItem">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
            Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
            Padding="5,0,5,0"/>
        <xctk:ColorPicker Grid.Column="1"
            SelectedColor="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEntityColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:PanelView}}}"
            Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NormalMenuItem" DataType="MenuItem">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
            Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**ListBox ContextMenu**

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding CadModelContextMenu}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PanelContextMenuItemDataTemplateSelector}"
        UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
        <ContextMenu.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Image x:Key="menuIcon" x:Shared="false"
                    Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Height="16px" Width="16px"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContextMenu.Resources>
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource menuIcon}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

The icon with this solution is different for each item. The icon is defined in the property of the underlaying object.